# interface and overriding the methods of the interface

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I'm 13 and quite new to java. What I can't seem to figure out is how NOT to implement overriding methods in a class from an interface because they are references. I don't want to make a new copy, and I can't just make (insert Class here) extend (the class the interface gets some of its methods from). So I implement it and what do i get?

```
err: The type Threadmanager must implement the inherited abstract method (the method)
```

and then it has a list, one of which says "implement uninherited methods".

But I dont want to implement any methods! I want to use them!

```
Threadmanager tm;
AwtUtils manager = tm;
manager.drawImage(/*params*/)
```

The above is what i want, the following is what i don't want:

```
@override
public void drawImage(/*params*/){
...
}
```

I don't want to redefine the methods in the interface, simply just use them. and I cant have class ThreadManager extends Debugger(.java) because it already extends something. I thought interfaces were a way you could use those methods in another class without inheriting them through "class foo extends bar"

By the way, all the methods referenced in the interface are references to methods in my class Debugger.java which doubles up as a debugger and the game library.

Comment: How are you going to use a method that hasn't been implemented anywhere?

Comment: The fact is: You must implement methods from interface.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Can you provide some more sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use methods from an interface. An interface has no code, only definitions. Think of it as a functionality *contract* that classes implementing it have to fulfill.

For example

```
public interface Example {
    public void method1ToImplement();
    public int method2ToImplement(final String input);
}
```

This is a contract that all classes implementing this interface must fulfill. This means any instantiable class that `implements Example` has to implement `public void method1ToImplement()` and `public int method2ToImplement(String)`. This is because you're stating this class fulfills this functionality, so you must implement this funcionality because as of now there's no code for this functionality in your class since the interface contains no code. For example, you cannot use the methods in `List`, in fact you cannot even create a new `List` because it's an interface. But you can create and `ArrayList` and use its methods because it's a non-abstract class implementing the `List` interface.

Maybe you're confused because you saw somewhere else you can use already implemented methods, for example `toString()` (which is already implemented in all classes). This is because this method is not defined in an interface but by a parent class (in case of `toString()` it's Object that implements it).

TL;DR: A class implementing an interface **must** implement its methods unless it's abstract.

Comment: I thought interfaces could hold references to other methods that other classes could implement to use those methods without becoming a subclass of the class that has the referenced methods in the interface!

Comment: Interfaces hold no references to anything. That way wouldn't work: how would you know what the implementation of those methods are and if that's what you want to use? How to change the "referenced" method? This is what classes (interface implementations) are for, not interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, you want a class to implement an interface, but don't implement its methods. If that's so, you cannot. Implementation of interface methods is mandatory, unless you're writing an *abstract class*.

I'm guessing there's something missing on your question, so please, provide some code of your `Interface` and `Class` so that we could give you a better answer.

Comment: well i have an interface and i only want to use the methods referenced. Is it inevitable to implement the method and have to have its own definition of the methods with @override?

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer See my answer, it may help clarify things.

Comment: Yes, actually as other users stated, interface methods are not defined at all. You can't use them without implementing them in a class because they does not 'exist', only their method signature.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about what an interface does.  An interface simply defines a contract such that any object which implements the interface must define the methods in the interface.  If you have an abstract class, then you must implement the abstract methods of said class for any class that extends the abstract class.  The only exception to this is when you `extend` from a class that has already implemented the abstract methods or interface and you don't want/need to redefine them for subclasses.

You say that you don't want to implement the methods, you just want to use them, but you can't use methods that don't exist.  Implementing an interface does not magically define the logic in the methods in the interface--that is your job.  Again, it simply states that any objects that implement the interface will have the interfaces' methods defined.

One of the nice things about interfaces is the following: Let's assume that we have a collection of objects that all implement a particular interface, then we can call any method from the interface on all those objects.  NB: we can group said objects together by having an array, ArrayList, or what have you that take the interface as the type parameter, ie `ArrayList<MyInterface>`

**More specific example:**
Let's consider a Shape interface that solely includes the header for an area method.  We can have a bunch of difference types of shapes that implement the Shape interface (circles, squares, etc).  In each shape class, we define a method to get the area for said shape.  Now, if we have an `ArrayList<Shape> shapes =...` we can put different types of shapes into that list and do the following:

```
for (Shape s : shapes)
{
     System.out.println(s.area());
}
```

Comment: oh ok i see now, but threadmanager isnt a subclass of anything in the package, its of something else. and the objects in the interface should not be abstract because i do not have anymore abstract classes in my game

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer I was just giving a general, overall explanation.  Nonetheless, hopefully things are clearer now.

Comment: thanks man, but if i can't use the interface, what alternative do i have to writing the methods in the class itself? i have a library that doubles as a debugger and library and it contains alot of methods. the class i have isnt a subclass of my library because it is a Threadmanager(hence the name)

Comment: Abstract classes are not something to not have. If it's required, you should have abstract classes.

Comment: If what you want is use methods in another class without passing the reference to that object around, you can look for static methods or the singleton pattern.