# Why can't I use the compare() method without making my class abstract?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, comparator

I'm currently trying to get the hang of inheritance and implementation but I can't get my head around why I need to implement interfaces, and why they aren't just normal methods.
Here is the code I'm currently writing that brought me to these questions, I'm trying to extend the ArrayList class so that elements are automatically sorted when entered.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Comparator;
/**
 * extending to ArrayList
 */
public abstract class SortedArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Comparator<E>
{

/**
 * Constructing the super
 */
public SortedArrayList()    
{
   super();

  }

  public  void insertAndSort (E element){
  if (isEmpty()){
      add(element);
    }

  for ( int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
      E otherElement = get(i);
      if(compare(element, otherElement) > 0){
          add(i+1, element);
        }
      if(compare(element, otherElement) < 0) {
          add(i-1, element);
        }
    }

}
}
```

note: I'm aware it's bad practice to extend an arrayList, it's just something I have to do. Also I'm not allowed to use sort().

I want to use the comparator to sort the ArrayList so I needed to implement it. However it wouldn't let me implement it without making the class abstract. I did so and although it meant I no longer get compiler errors I don't fully understand what it means to make an abstract class and what repercussions it will have. Am I doing the right thing?
Thanks.

Comment: When implementing an `interface` you have to implement its methods (or make the implementing class `abstract`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [interface and overriding the methods of the interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758055/interface-and-overriding-the-methods-of-the-interface)

Comment: Where do you think you've implemented the `compare` method at the moment? What do you expect to execute when you call `compare(element, otherElement)`? It's not clear *why* you've decided to implement `Comparator`, either...

Comment: sorry I'm pretty new to this. I thought it was in the for loop? I'm trying to iterate through an arraylist of objects and sort them in ascending order

Comment: No. You you cant use the compare() method if you had an non-abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not doing the right thing. You should not declare the `Comparator` interface, but get an instance of it in the constructor for example.

The `abstract` modifier means you cannot create an instance of this class without providing an implementation to the `compare` method, so at the end you have to implement that method. It is more reusable if it is a separate object (you can use existing implementations).

Edit: (composition is preferred over inheritance in this case)

```
private final Comparator<E> comparator;
//constructor
SortedArrayList(Comparator<E> cmptor) {
   this.comparator = cmptor;
}
```

and when you have to compare items, you can use `comparator.compare` instead of `compare`.

Comment: If I put it in the constructor would that mean I wouldn't have to declare it in the interface, would not have to make the class abstract, and subsequently my compare() methods would work?

Comment: Updated a bit the answer with a simple example how you can save the constructor parameter in a field.

Comment: BTW: It seems you might add too often the new elements (at most as many times as elements are there when it is not empty), though I can be wrong in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to implement the interface instead of just providing a method in your class is that java helps you keep track of your methods that way.

If you were to just implement the method and got it slightly wrong, without interfaces java wouldn't know what you were trying to do at compile time, you'd have to wait until runtime to catch a mispelling in the method name, and even then you might not detect it.

A system that just detects that you have a method and allows a caller to use it is called "Duck Typing".  There are a lot of languages that do this, Java is just providing you with more help than a language with duck typing does.

For instance, if you are using an IDE like Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ (you absolutely should be, otherwise you can't take advantage of many features of Java), the editor/java will lead you through the steps you need automatically.

The interaction should go something like this:

- You call a method that takes a Comparitor and pass in an object.
- Eclipse gives you an error telling you that your object does not implement Comparable
- You add "implements Comparable" to your object.
- Eclipse tells you that your "Comparable" object is incomplete because it doesn't implement the compare method.  It has a lightbulb providing at least 2 viable solutions:
- 1) Eclipse will make it "abstract" (indicating the class isn't finished)
- 2) Eclipse will implement the needed methods for you
- You click the add methods solution and it adds the entire method signature including parameter and return value types.
- You fill in the insides of your new method and are done.

This may seem like a lot of steps, but has the advantages that: A) even if you are unsure at each step, you are always warned as you type and are prompted as to what you need to do--a large time savings! and B) Everything is provided to you in the editor, you don't ever need to go to documentation to solve the problem once you know the process.

This process works for everything in Java, even with external libraries you can often code with little or no knowledge of the library, just an editor, and interfaces are a large part of that process.

If you are interested in seeing how your Java class would work with Duck Typing, you could download Groovy.  The groovy language follows and extends Java so you could take your same java class and run it through Groovy--but you can then start taking advantage of dynamic features like Duck Typing where you don't need to implement the interface, you just implement the method and it works.